# How to shorten/simplify Javascript code to make an interactive text?

Tags: javascript, html, text, interactive

I've written this simple code to make an interactive text application. The text will be much longer and more complex. I'm sure I could make it simpler (for instance, using 1 function instead of many), but I don't know how.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

```js
     function showHighBP() {
            var x = document.getElementById("highBP");
            if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
                document.getElementById("diabetes").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("asthma").style.display = "none";
                x.style.display = "inline";
            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        
        function showDiabetes() {
            var x = document.getElementById("diabetes");
            if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
                document.getElementById("highBP").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("asthma").style.display = "none";
                x.style.display = "inline";
            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

            function showAsthma() {
            var x = document.getElementById("asthma");
            if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display == "") {
                document.getElementById("highBP").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("diabetes").style.display = "none";
                x.style.display = "inline";
            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

```css
.hidden { 
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button onclick=showHighBP()>High Blood Pressure</button>
        <button onclick=showDiabetes()>Diabetes</button>
        <button onclick=showAsthma()>Asthma</button>
        
        <br/>
        <p>
            <span>The diagnosis is</span>
            <span class="hidden" id="highBP">high blood pressure.</span>
            <span class="hidden" id="diabetes">diabetes.</span>
            <span class="hidden" id="asthma">asthma.</span>
        </p>
            
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Deniz! Welcome to SO! One method of reducing the amount of code to one function is by having a showText() function instead of three seperate functions. In your button, when you click, call showText() function with a value such as "highBloodPressure" or "diabetes" or "asthma" and have the showText() function check the passed in parameter and execute the appropriate behaviour.

Comment: I've really tried that (see following example) but it didn't work, it has something to do with the sintax I guess:

<button onclick=showText(highBP)>High Blood Pressure</button>
<span id="disease"></span>

function showText(whichDisease) {
         if (whichDisease = "highBP") {
         document.getElementById("disease").innerHTML = "high blood pressure."
     }

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to wrap the function you're passing to your onclick attribute in double quotation marks and the string values you're passing into the showText() function in single quotation marks?

eg:

```js
<button onclick="showText('highBP')">High Blood Pressure</button>
```

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work. I've just posted a new question with a simpler code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You need to wrap the function and the string in single and double quotes. Compare the two lines of button code and you'll see you're missing the quotation marks. Without them or mixing them up causes your code to not execute.